Use of Timers on a Pcollection in Apache Beam
I have a use case where I need to write a beam job (Flink on Beam), using Timers and State.
I tried following this wiki https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/, but I was getting an error saying timers, states can be used only on KV pairs. However the example shared in the beam wiki does not use KV pairs. An I missing something here? Is there any way I can use timers without converting my PCollection of elements into a Pcollection of KV pairs?

Yes it is not explicitly stated in the code, but if you read carefully it says you need states.  The colors of the elements represent their key, which will matter later (quote from the second sentance of the second paragraph of the first section)

Thanks for the response @CaptainNabla. Is there any reason why we can use Timers only on KV pairs? I have a use case where I need to collect elements for 5 mins and then write the elements collected during the last 5 min using a custom writer (DoFn). I want to collect the elements and call the write function periodically every 5 minutes. What is the best way to do this if I cannot use Timers?

Hi @Vamsi, Could you have a look at this stack link ? Let me know if this helps for your requirements or not.

Hi @DhirajSingh, in the stack link you shared, it already has input as KV pair. I just have a pcollection of elements and it seems that the timer and state only work on KV.

If you want to apply the same time to every incoming element, just put a dummy key (i.e., the same key) on all incoming data.

@CaptainNabla Adding a dummy key is adding an extra step for shuffle. Looks like all the keys are coming to a single node after the shuffle, which might become a bottle neck right? Is there any other way that you could think of to avoid shuffle? Do you think it is a good idea to add a custom scheduler, that periodically flushes the data to the writer?

As mentioned by @CaptainNabla in the comments, Yes it is not explicitly stated in the code, but if you read carefully it says you need states.  The colors of the elements represent their key, which will matter later (quote from the second sentence of the second paragraph of the first section).
If you want to apply the same time to every incoming element, just put a dummy key (i.e., the same key) on all incoming data.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
